# Bad modify timestamp is shown when reading from shared folder with explorer

Tags: windows, sharepoint

I'm viewing a SharePoint folder like

```
http://server/portal/subfolder
```

as a network share instead

```
\\server\portal\subfolder
```

with the Windows explorer, but on some files (not all) it's showing bad modify timestamps.
Are there any known bugs and/or workarounds to this?

Answer (score 0):

Compare timestamps of files shown in explorer to the timestamps shown for the same files by DIR/OD in a command shell.

We have systems, where timestamps of local files, dated before mid november show 1 hour difference while later ones do not. Pretty strange, but microsoft had at least 2 timezone fixes in last last months, with the december fix fixing the august fix. And Microsofts track record regarding fixes could be better these days.